# Parsing huge file in Node.js faster, reading the file line-by-line, currently running too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have got a very big text file with over 15m records. It's a vocabulary file which shows the word on the left and the occurrence of the word on the right. The end result I am looking for is to filter out all these words and any words that occur less than 200 times are classed as difficult words.

For example, this is what the text file will have inside:

```
of  12765289150
and 12522922536
```

The word on the left and the occurrence on the right separated by a tab.

Currently, the system I have in place returns me the words which occur `<=` 200 times which is great but it takes over 15 seconds to read through the file and return these values. How could I speed this process up?

This is the code that I am running:

```
exports.readText = (req, res, next) => {
  const fs = require('fs'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    path = require("path"),
    filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../documents/vocab_cs");

  const infrequentWords = [];

  let s = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync((line) => {
        const lines = line.split('\t');
        const freq = Number(lines[1]);
        if (freq <= 200) {
          infrequentWords.push(lines[0]);
        }
        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        // process line here and call s.resume() when rdy

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        s.resume();
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        infrequentWordsString = infrequentWords.join(' ');
        res.status(200).json(infrequentWordsString);
        console.log('Read entire file.')
      })
    );
}
```

Any advice would be highly appreciated as I do not have much experience in this field and I am completely stuck on this issue!

Just need this whole process to run much faster and return me these rare words `<= 200`, because they get displayed on the frontend to help readers understand the text better, but with this delay, the user would have to wait over 10/15 seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it HAVE to be a text file? Is the file updated? If so how frequently?

Comment: No, the file is not updated. It can be anything as long as those values are scanned through. @Creynders

Comment: If it's not updated, I'd simply store the relevant values into a separate text file and use that instead. Or better yet, store them in a JS array.

Comment: Sounds good, but the issue with this is that when I put over 8million words into an array I seem to get memory issues. I will try the file thing you mentioned which was going to be one of my possible solutions but even with that, it will still be very slow. Maybe Il try the JS array, but with that, I fear that I might get memory issues. @Creynders (thanks for the advice) if you think of anything else please let me know, il keep you updated with my progress.

Comment: @Creynders Issue I am having now is when I pass it over to the frontend the frontend freezes. Its roughly passing over about 54,000 words. Not sure how I could fix this...

Comment: This is all fixed now, the issue still is that it takes too long to read the document, is there a faster way for the initial read? @Creynders

Comment: Optimisation is hard and 99.99% of the times you'll need to employ several techniques. It's all very context and use case specific. Anyway, the first thing I'd try is an in-memory data store and run benchmarks on how much faster it is and whether it's worth the effort. E.g. redis: https://redis.io/

Comment: For instance depending on the use case it might involve all of these combined: a flat file structure, a database, an in-memory caching tier, a bloom filter implementation to fail fast and a levenshtein algorithm implementation for further lookup. But most often it also involves all kinds of UI tricks to give the impression of speed (which is more important than the actual speed). E.g. a screen locking up for 1 second seems to take WAY longer than a requesting-loading-responding visualisation of 1.5 seconds